# InvalidCastException when trying to make a list from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I'm trying to make a table in a web application using MVC that reads information from an xml file. I'm trying to order this list before sending it back to the controller but there is an InvalidCastException on my orderby line. What am I doing wrong?

```
string xmlData = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/HighScores.xml");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlData);
var scores = new List<ExternalScoreModel>();

try
{
    scores = (from r in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
              orderby r.Field<Int32>("Score") descending
              select new ExternalScoreModel
              {
                  Score = Convert.ToInt32(r[0]),
                  FirstName = r[1].ToString(),
                  LastName = r[2].ToString(),
              }).ToList();
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
{
    //TODO
}
return scores;
```

Fixed it by moving the orderby until after the select

```
scores = (from r in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                      select new ExternalScoreModel
                      {
                          Score = Convert.ToInt32(r[0]),
                          FirstName = r[1].ToString(),
                          LastName = r[2].ToString(),
                      }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToList();
```

Comment: What does your xml data look like?

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess: "Score" is being stored as a string, so `r.Field<Int32>("Score")` fails since there is no cast available. You will have to order after using `Convert.ToInt...`.

Comment: Why not use LinqToXML instead of all this DataSet hoopla?

Comment: You should make your "fixed it" section into a separate answer so that others with the same problem will know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the "Score" column is most likely not an Int. Double check the data in the XML file. The Value may also be missing or is null in which case you can do something like the below and assign a score of 0 or whatever else you would want.

```
 orderby r.Field<Int32?>("Score") == null ? 0 : r.Field<Int32>("Score") descending
```

Comment: You were right, the data in "Score" was initially a string and I converted it to an int later. But I actually just figured it out before you got back to me, I just took the orderby r.Field<Int32>("Score") descending out and then added a .OrderByDescending just before the .ToList()

Comment: That works as well. You could have also kept it the way you had it and orderby on score as a string and it still should have sorted correctly.

Comment: @LoganGilmore was this answer helpful?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't fully understand how to use it properly before but I have a much better understanding now. I just went with the fix I found but I agree that your method definitely should work as well. Thanks @AnimalStyle